# How to choose sigma and epsilon value for carbon to calculate the bond coeff (lj units) in LAMMPS?

Tags: lammps

I want to calculate the bond coefficient values to be used in bond_coeff command in LAMMPS input file. According to LAMMPS documentation:

https://docs.lammps.org/units.html

x*=x/sigma gives me the unitless (lj units) value of distance. my question is what is the related sigma and epsilon for Carbon-Carbon ? (I have a triangular lattice)

In general how or where to find the sigma and epsilon values for different materials?

Does any body know the C-C bond coeffiecient value in lj units?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for literature where people have used different potentials for your elements. LJ potential is fine to start with, but it has very less degree of freedom so that many different properties cannot be matched.
A well know database given in open-kim website for different elements in periodic table and corresponding LJ parameters.
https://openkim.org/files/MO_959249795837_003/LennardJones612_UniversalShifted.params

Comment: Thank you so much, great help